# Throughput of TCP and UDP

Tags: tcp, network-programming, udp

If we have a some Mbps connection between source and destination and known latency and the source has two processes sending data via TCP and UDP respectively, which of two process will have a higher throughput and how to calculate it?

I am not a computer science student and I don't know networks.

Comment: There's no way to know in advance which has the higher throughput. It would depend on many factors we have no way to know. (It also depends on how you define throughput. Does data sent but not received count? Does data received but that the sender doesn't know was received count?) The easiest way to calculate is to ask each process to send a known amount of data and time how long they take.

Comment: In general, UDP will have higher throughput because the protocol is simpler and the protocol headers are smaller so each packet can contain a bigger payload. On the other hand there is no built-in reliability in UDP, which will most probably cause dropped packages which of course lowers throughput.

Answer (score 2):

TCP and UDP are both using the IP layer and will both have the same network available to them.  Depending on the protocol you use you *could* get more throughput via UDP.  This would require you to write a protocol to transfer data that was more aggressive than TCP or discard data without having to resend it.

If you did write a protocol more aggressive than TCP it would likely be banned by anyone managing a network that came into contact with it since it will degrade TCP sessions on that network.

If you could discard any data that came through then you wouldn't waste the bandwidth resending the lost packets in TCP and UDP would be a more natural choice but since you care about bandwidth I'm guessing that thats not the case?